# Beautiful Soup Cleaning and Errors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from lxml import html
from lxml.etree import tostring 
trees = urllib2.urlopen('http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/index?                             station_ids=KJFK&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&ch    k_tafs=on&submit=Submit').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(trees))
print soup.get_text()
item=soup.findAll(id="info")
print item
```

However, when I type soup on my window it gives me an error and when my program runs it gives me a very long html code with

and so on. Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is in this part:

```
trees = urllib2.urlopen('http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/index?station_ids=KJFK&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submit=Submit').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(trees))
```

`trees` is a file-like object, there is no need to call `open()` on it, fix it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(trees, "html.parser")
```

We are also explicitly setting the `html.parser` as an underlying parser.

---

Then, you need to be *specific* about what you are going to extract from a page. Here is the example code to get the `METAR text` value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


trees = urllib2.urlopen('http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/index?station_ids=KJFK&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&chk_tafs=on&submit=Submit').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(trees, "html.parser")

item = soup.find("strong", text="METAR text:").find_next("strong").get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", "")
print item
```

Prints `KJFK 220151Z 20016KT 10SM BKN250 24/21 A3007 RMK AO2  SLP183 T02440206`.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. I will make these changes.

Comment: I am now having problem with it as I made those upgrades but now I want to use url to get http://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=JFK&p=0  but it is giving me this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'